# Writing text to file in android

Tags: android, file, text

I am trying to do write to text to txt.file.

```
myOutWriter.append
```

I use this method but If i do this second I lose my  first values. Everytime I see Text file
with 1 record. What am i supposed to do ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000850/appending-file-results-in-overwrite-java

Comment: Show us your `new FileOutputStream` line.

Comment: In you constructor of FileWriter add second parameter with "true" value. This parameter tells whether or not the writer should append to old file or rewrite it (true if you want to append)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000850/appending-file-results-in-overwrite-java   That works Ken. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the `FileWriter` in append mode.

```
FileWriter myOutWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
```

Then append should work seamlessly.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```